# Is there an async I/O based Aws java client?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jetty

1) Is there an implementation of the [aws sdk](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/) which uses asynchronous I/O instead of thread pools? I am working on a highly scalable web service and profiling shows that the CPU is wasting a lot of cycles managing network I/O to and from amazon.

2)The current client uses [Apache Http Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/), if I cannot find an asynch implementation I will fork my own version to implement it. I was thinking of using the [Jetty Http Client](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Jetty+HTTP+Client). Is it bad form to mix Jetty and Apache libraries? Is there a better alternative?

Comment: _"CPU bottle neck is all the connections to amazon"_ No, that's a (network) I/O  bottleneck. A CPU bottleneck is, **by definition,** in the CPU.

Comment: You are right the network is the bottle neck but I don't want to waste CPU time and threads on that network I/O. The hprof report shows that a majority of cpu samples occur in polling the sockets.

Comment: The difference is what you hope to gain.  Asynchronous I/O can't save you from service latency: it does not make AWS' handling of your request magically faster on their end.  It might, however, let you do more meaningful local computation while you wait.  So would a thread pool, for that matter.

Comment: How can it be highly scalable if you have a backend bottleneck?

Comment: @phs "It might, however, let you do more meaningful local computation" exactly, and we are sending thousands of requests to AWs which means that open requests tend to pile up. having blocked threads for open requests seems more inefficient than using NIO.

Comment: @ Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, Its scalable across nodes the AWS bottle neck is only on a given node. To clarify the aws service is not slow and that is not what I hope to optimize here. The number of threads is easting CPU which is causing delays larger than the service delays.

Comment: It's 2015 and the SDK stil uses IO. I wonder if that 2008 paper is still valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1) Is there an implementation of the aws sdk which uses asynchronous
>   I/O instead of thread pools?

Not that I know of, and I'd be surprised this to be difficult to find, if it would exist already.

> 2) The current client uses Apache Http Client, if I cannot find an
>   asynch implementation I will fork my own version to implement it. [...] Is there a better 
>   alternative?

There is a better alternative indeed - the [AWS SDK for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/) currently uses the [Http Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) version 4.x (you linked to the legacy 3.1 version JavaDocs instead) from [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/), which conveniently provides a [Async HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/index.html) as well:

> [Async HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/index.html) is a HTTP/1.1 compliant HTTP agent implementation
>   **based on HttpCore NIO** and HttpClient components. It is a complementary
>   module to Apache HttpClient **intended for special cases where ability
>   to handle a great number of concurrent connections is more important
>   than performance** in terms of a raw data throughput. *[emphasis mine]*

As emphasized, it should only be facilitated for respective uses cases, but (as per [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251534/is-there-an-async-i-o-based-aws-java-client/9251891#comment11657326_9251534)) you are *sending thousands of requests to AWs which means that open requests tend to pile up*, so this might help indeed.

Comment: Finally someone answered the question asked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Asynchronous IO is not a silver bullet - thread-per-connection is usually faster (throughput-wise) and a lot easier to code:

http://www.mailinator.com/tymaPaulMultithreaded.pdf

It sounds to me like your limiting factor is the IO to Amazon, not the CPU processing of all those connections. The fact that you are seeing a lot of CPU time spent polling the sockets may just be a profiling artifact due to the fact that those calls block. (Something to check: are you actually maxing out CPU usage?)

Answer (score 2):

The new **AWS SDK for Java 2.0 preview** was [announced](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/now-available-developer-preview-of-aws-sdk-for-java-2-0/) at June 2017 and provides this functionality.

> The SDK now supports truly non-blocking I/O. The 1.11.x version of the SDK already has async variants of service clients. However, they are just a wrapper around a thread pool and the blocking sync client, so they don’t provide the benefits of non-blocking I/O (high concurrency with very few threads). Due to the limitations and poor resource use of the thread-per-connection model, many customers requested support for non-blocking I/O, so we are pleased to announce first class support for non-blocking I/O in our async clients. Under the hood, we use an HTTP client built on top of Netty to make the non-blocking HTTP call.

For more information, see

- [Announcement by Jeff Bar](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/now-available-developer-preview-of-aws-sdk-for-java-2-0/)
- [Original blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/aws-sdk-for-java-2-0-developer-preview/)
- [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/basics.html)
- [Github repo](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2)

However, be aware:

- Currently in preview (not recommended for production use yet)
- Needs Java 8+

**UPDATE (Jan. 2019)**

Current version is 2.3.0 (for a long time out of preview).

Recommended is to use this BOM in maven based projects:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```